# Java - How do I say I don't care what this part of the string contains?

Tags: java, file, selenium

I've got a bit of code, where I get the timestamp, however I want to be able to say that I don't care what seconds it is, so... this is the code I have:

```
    String timeStampString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    File fileName = new File(universal + "/Downloads/" + timeStampString);
    String newName = "allPi.csv";
    if (fileName.exists()) {
        fileName.renameTo(new File(universal + "/Downloads/allPi.csv"));
    }
    else
    {
        Assert.fail();
    }
```

The downloaded file will have a full timestamp down to seconds, how do I say that I don't care what numbers are in the seconds part, like timeStampString + "**"; or something??

I've tried a few random things like:

```
   File fileName = new File(universal + "/Downloads/" + timeStampString + "[.+]");
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: Example contents of `timeStampString`: `201609131013` no seconds...

Comment: You can't do that with a Java File, you could use [Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html) to get a list of filenames corresponding to your criteria, and then open is. That, by the way, is also a problem you need to address, you may not always get exactly 1 file in return (sometimes more than one, sometimes none).

Comment: Use the `FileSystem` API. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher(java.lang.String)

Comment: Hello, I'd only get 1 since I have a separate Java app to delete these files once they're checked over, essentially my issue is that I am unable to say this:
Okay great i got my yyyymmddhhmm and I want to use that to find my file that I just downloaded, however I don't care what second it is, so as such I'd like a string where I can say "/Download/" + timeStampString + "Whatever seconds"
Any ideas :)??

Comment: You can't write use a regex/pattern for a file name. What you can do, though, is get all the files in the directory, and then filter them down.

Comment: @Marko Hello, as a newbie, I got to ask I imported java.nio.file.*; lib, however I don't really understand how to implement, can you assist? Cheers, sorry to be a pain.

Comment: @4castle Would suggestion written by Marko not work? If so, why? And if it really wouldn't could you post a more elaborate answer?
Since I am only adding a part to a file which is a string, I'm hoping it will work?

Comment: @MG97 The suggestion from Marko is one way to filter down the files, but isn't actually a complete solution for how to get the files in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't use the [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class. It is an outdated, badly written class which should not be used in new code, as better alternatives have existed since Java 1.4 or so.

Instead, use [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) and [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html). They have many methods that allow you to do common tasks, and in addition have better error reporting.

In this particular case, you can use a [`DirectoryStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html), which comes from the same family of classes ([`java.nio.file`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html)). A `DirectoryStream` is an iterable object of files in a directory. And the `Files` class allows you to get a `DirectoryStream` of all the files in the directory that match a *glob* pattern. Glob patterns are the familiar patterns like `*.java` or `Name-xyz-?.txt`.

In your case you assume that you'll have only one entry. So you just need the first entry in the associated iterator.

```
Path dir = Paths.get( universal, "Downloads" );
Path renameTo = Paths.get( universal, "Downloads", "allPi.txt" );
try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, timeStampString + "*" )) {
    Iterator<Path> iterator = stream.iterator();
    if ( iterator.hasNext() ) {
        Path path = iterator.next();
        Files.move( path, renameTo, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING );
    }
}
```

Of course, have try-catch for any exceptions.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply, I can confirm it worked, as a beginner I'm not sure - where could I go read about this more so I can understand it better.

Also do you write these things from memory or do you use something to refer to? I'm interested as this is a lot of things to remember....

I'm also not sure as to how to add try catch, purely because of my lack of knowledge, but thanks I'll look into those.

Comment: @MG97 You need to remember basic things as you gain experience, but basically, everybody refers in one way or another to the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/). The API is perhaps not the place to learn the basic techniques - you can use the [Oracle tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) for this.

Comment: 1.4 "or so"? Nothing got improved until Java 7 and you won't believe how many projects are still stuck with Java 6.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `java.nio.file` API instead:

```
Path directory = Paths.get(universal, "Downloads");
Path path = Files.list(directory).filter((Path p) -> {
                String fileName = p.getFileName().toString();
                return fileName.startsWith(timeStampString);
            })
            .findAny()
            .orElse(null);

if (path == null) {
     Assert.fail();
} else {
    Files.move(path, directory.resolve("allPi.csv"));
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply, I used  skeptics answer, thank you for the reply though :)

Comment: I believe you can use [`startsWith`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#startsWith-java.nio.file.Path-) directly on the file name path without converting `toString()`

Comment: @4castle No: [Tests if this path starts with a `Path`, constructed by converting the given path string, in exactly the manner specified by the `startsWith(Path)` method. On UNIX for example, the path "foo/bar" starts with "foo" and "foo/bar". It does not start with "f" or "fo".](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Ah, makes sense. For stylistic purposes though, you should probably convert it to a lambda that doesn't have a block and a return statement. You can chain the statements together into a single statement with no `{}`, and it will be much easier to read.

Comment: Also, the `Optional` class is a great alternative to using a `null` value. I would just use an `Optional<Path>` and then check if it [`isPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#isPresent--)

Comment: @4castle I deliberately chose not to use `isPresent`, since Java Language Architect Brian Goetz seems to consent to some critique on `isPresent`, see http://royvanrijn.com/blog/2016/04/deprecating-optional-get/ and http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2016-April/040531.html ; regarding the lambda expression: It seems to be highly likely that some additional checks could be added to the `Path`, like ending, so I chose the more elaborate code.

Comment: Interesting. So the most elegant solution would probably be if we could use `orElseThrow` (which is what I assume the `Assert.fail()` is for). `Assert.fail()` should be replaced with a more informative unchecked exception.